# Geometric explanation of Hutton's formula?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, plane-geometry, trigonometric-sums

$$\frac{\pi}{4} = 2 \tan^{-1} \frac{1}{3} + \tan^{-1} \frac{1}{7} \;.$$
Is there some geometric construction that explains this beautiful equation
(known as [Hutton's formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HuttonsFormula.html))?
Perhaps a "proof without words" figure that makes it self-evident?

---

Here is Figure 1a from the reference Henry provided:

> Nelsen, Roger B. "Proof Without Words: The Formulas of Hutton and Strassnitzky." *Mathematics Magazine* **86** 5 (2013): 350-350.
>   
>    
>    
>    
>    
>    
>   [image: Fig1a]

Comment: Roger Nelsen gave a proof without words in Math Magazine 86 (2013), 350.  See www.jstor.org/stable/10.4169/math.mag.86.5.350.

Comment: What a lovely proof!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

All of these [Machin-like formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machin-like_formula) have proofs-without-words. First, notice that there is a one line proof using the Gaussian integers:
$$(3+i)^2 (7+i) = 50 + 50 i.$$
Taking arguments of both sides proves the result (modulo $2 \pi$).

Now, plot the products
$$3 \times 3 \times 7=63,\qquad  (3+i) \times 3 \times 7=63+21 i,$$
$$(3+i)^2 \times 7 = 56+42i,\qquad (3+i)^2 (7+i) = 50+50 i.$$
Here the $3$'s and $7$'s are the real parts of $3+i$ and $7+i$.

Each consecutive pair of complex numbers forms a right triangle with the third vertex at $0$:
$$(0,63, 63+21i),\ (0, 63+21i, 56+42i),\ (0, 56+42i, 50+50 i).$$
Draw each of those triangles and you have a proof without words.

---

[image]

 
 
 
 
 
<sub>(Image added by J.O'Rourke)</sub>

Comment: Thank you, David, this is a beautifully clarifying viewpoint!

Comment: You're welcome! Sorry for the missing scalar factors in the first version; added now.

Answer (score 6):

A similar argument was found by pappus on the French forum [les-mathematiques.net](http://www.les-mathematiques.net/phorum/read.php?8,689458,690552#msg-690552).

[image]